# How to group configs by environment in python?

Tags: python

I'm developing a complex ETL process from scratch. The process uses multiprocessing and database queries with SQLAlchemy. Now I'm trying to add a file environmnet configuration where like:

```
dev -> database config connection, folder where save temporal files, folder where save log files.
test -> another database config connection, another folder where save temporal files, another folder where save log files.
```

The current project strucures is:

```
package_1
    some_module_1.py
    some_module_2.py
    main_process.py <-- Cron job will run it
package_2
    another_some_module_1.py
    another_main_process.py <-- Another Cron job will run it
```

At runtime (maybe?) it sets the environment to take configuration set.
How can I do it? What is your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a configuration file per environment, for example with python's [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/configparser.html).

To select the one you want, you can set an environment variable and [read it in your python code](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.environ).